# Python arguments are read as code

Tags: python, macos, ascii, getopt

When attempting to run a Python script, for example:

```
python test.py --test 'Test'
```

it appeared that getopt was failing. And printing sys.argv revealed:

```
['test.py', '\xe2\x80\x94-test', '\xe2\x80\x9cTest\xe2\x80\x9d']
```

I was copying and pasting the command into Terminal on OS X.  The command was in a text file that may have been saved on Windows. What's a possible reason for this, as I haven't had this issue before?

If I retype the command in Terminal it works fine.  Is there a way to process the arguments in the script so it interprets them correctly?

Comment: Was it really a text file, or was it something like a Word doc?

Comment: It may have been in Notepad++ on Windows or in TextWrangler on OS X.  But it was probably copied in/out of a temporary new file, and as a new, unsaved file, didn't have the appropriate format settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Windows editor replaced a regular dash with an em-dash, and the quotes with 'fancy' styled quoting:

```
>>> '\xe2\x80\x94-test'.decode('utf8')
u'\u2014-test'
>>> print '\xe2\x80\x94-test'.decode('utf8')
—-test
>>> '\xe2\x80\x9cTest\xe2\x80\x9d'.decode('utf8')
u'\u201cTest\u201d'
>>> print '\xe2\x80\x9cTest\xe2\x80\x9d'.decode('utf8')
“Test”
>>> import unicodedata
>>> for u in u'\u2014\u201c\u201d':
...     print u, unicodedata.name(u)
... 
— EM DASH
“ LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
” RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
```

Use a text-oriented editor next time; a word processor is liable to replace text with 'prettier' versions.

You could do `unicode.translate()` calls:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.argv = ['test.py', '\xe2\x80\x94-test', '\xe2\x80\x9cTest\xe2\x80\x9d']
>>> map = {0x2014: u'-', 0x201c: u"'", 0x201d: u"'"}
>>> sys.argv[1:] = [s.decode('utf8').translate(map).encode('utf8') for s in sys.argv[1:]]
>>> sys.argv
['test.py', '--test', "'Test'"]
```

Note that the shell will not parse whitespace correctly because it has no regular quotes to work with; you may want to translate your text file using the above method *first*, then paste the properly quoted strings into the shell.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  I suppose I won't try to decode, but instead somehow detect that there's a problem, then print a warning to the terminal with the arguments that aren't parsing.